# WHERE NOT EXISTS in MySQL : Inserting into table if one data of a field name exist?

Tags: php, mysql

My database structure

```
id | name | contact | location

 1 | ABC  | 012444452 | Koh
```

How to not insert other data into database if contact number is the same(exist) and skip.

my query

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO test(name, contact, location) VALUES ('$name', '$contact', '$location')");
```

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate, and if not, very relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18114458/fastest-way-to-determine-if-record-exists

Comment: before inserting data just check whether it is already in db or not

Comment: why not just use a UNIQUE constraint? a lot simpler.

Comment: What fred said, if it has to be unique then put a unique constraint on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `WHERE NOT EXISTS` with INSERT.

```
"INSERT INTO test(name, contact, location)
 VALUES ('$name', '$contact', '$location') 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM test WHERE `name`= '$name')".
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Subic C Poonamgode i dont know if you still can help, but should this work with php and mysqli using mysql database?