# Need a universal query to check if row exists using 'EXISTS' keyword

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, postgresql

The following query works for PostgreSQL and MS SQL but not for MYSQL

```
SELECT 1 as retVal WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM posts WHERE topic = 'Sports')
```

And the following query works for PostgreSQL and MySQL but not for MS SQL

```
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM posts WHERE topic = 'Sports')
```

Need a query which works for all three vendors.

Answer (score 5):

Use `case` for these databases:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM posts WHERE topic = 'Sports')
             THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) as retval
```

This will not work in databases that require a `FROM` clause (such as Oracle and DB2).  You can fix that by creating a table called `dual` and just having it in the database:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM posts WHERE topic = 'Sports')
             THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) as retval
FROM dual;
```

Or, the following should work in any database:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as retval
FROM posts
WHERE topic = 'Sports';
```

However, it is less efficient than the version using `EXISTS`.

Comment: Thanks, Gordon. I'll go for the fist solution as it supports all of my required vendors. 
The third solution is not an option for me as I'm rewriting the query which already using COUNT. I needed a faster solution which EXISTS provides.