# Is these a simple way to determine whether exist a record by id using Room?

Tags: android, android-room

The following code is based the project https://github.com/enpassio/Databinding

I hope to determine whether exist a record by id, so I write the following code.

I think my code is not good, is these a simple way to determine whether exist a record by id using Room?

Can I directly a SQl and return Booean with @Dao? If so, how can I do?

**Code**

```
@Dao
interface ToyDao {

    @get:Query("SELECT * FROM toys")
    val allToys: LiveData<List<ToyEntry>>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM toys WHERE toyId = :id")
    fun getChosenToy(id: Int): LiveData<ToyEntry>

    ...
}



class ToyRepository private constructor(private val mDatabase: ToyDatabase, private val mExecutors: AppExecutors) {

    val toyList: LiveData<List<ToyEntry>>
        get() = mDatabase.toyDao().allToys

    fun getChosenToy(toyId: Int): LiveData<ToyEntry> {
        return mDatabase.toyDao().getChosenToy(toyId)
    }

    
    
    fun isExistRecord(toyId: Int):Boolean{
        val my=getChosenToy(toyId)
        if (my.value==null) return false else return true
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to [@Yarin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62631357/9629748), codes below I test can simply work.

```
@Query("SELECT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM _table WHERE _id = :id)")
fun exists(id: Id): Boolean
```

---

But as I test, it seems not speed up with this method, maybe I'm not write in good way..

### Environment

Emulator Pixel 2 API 28

100000+ Rows

Query 10000 times in 1372ms

```
@Query("SELECT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM _table WHERE _id = :id)")
fun exists(id: Long): Boolean
```

Query 10000 times in 1364ms

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM _table WHERE _id = :id")
fun getItem(id: Long): Item
```

---

### UPDATE

You can use `LIMIT` as `TOP` in `SQLite`, and usually here uses `List` for multiple results
( if LIMIT is not 1 ).

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM _table WHERE _id = :id LIMIT 1")
fun getItem(id: Long): List<Item>
```

and it could be also `Item` because we know the result will be single.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM _table WHERE _id = :id LIMIT 1")
fun getItem(id: Long): Item
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I write `@Dao interface ToyDao{... }` for `SELECT TOP 1 toys.id FROM toys WHERE toys.id = :id` ?

Comment: It seems using `LIMIT` in `SQLite`, so it would be `SELECT * FROM _table WHERE _id = :id LIMIT 1`

Comment: Thanks! Could you give me the code ? I don't know what `SELECT * FROM _table WHERE _id = :id LIMIT 1  ` will return.

Answer (score 1):

you can check out this thread [fastest-way-to-determine-if-record-exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18114458/fastest-way-to-determine-if-record-exists)

basically you have 2 options:

1. use the  `TOP 1` and it will look like - `SELECT TOP 1 toys.id FROM toys WHERE toys.id = :id`
2. use `EXISTS` or `NO EXISTS` and it will look like -

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM toys WHERE id = :id)
BEGIN
--do what you need if exists
END
ELSE
BEGIN
--do what needs to be done if not
END
```

Comment: Thanks! How can express your ideas in `@Dao interface ToyDao{... }`'  ?

Comment: simply write :

`@Query("SELECT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM toys WHERE toyId = :id)")
fun selectToyIfExists(id: Int): LiveData<ToyEntry>`

Comment: Thanks! are you sure that `@Query("SELECT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM toys WHERE toyId = :id)") fun selectToyIfExists(id: Int)` will return `LiveData<ToyEntry>` ?

Comment: you are right it wont, it will return a boolean (true) if it does exist. if you want to retrieve the actual `LiveData<ToyEntry>` then use it and if it returns true then just simply use the query `"(SELECT * FROM toys WHERE toyId = :id)"` since you already know the toy exists