# find if specific row has a value in it through sql query

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, db2

I have a table structured like so:

10 columns named `report1` -> `report10`, a `childName` column, and `parentId` column. I need to upload a url to one of the report columns dynamically. So when I hit the `upload` on my front end, it sends a request to the backend, which I need to say, return data from table where the childName = the passed childName. Easy enough, I have this:

```
var viewStudents = "select * from reportsfor where CHILDNAME = '" + studentName + "'";
```

but where my issue lies, is the fact that I need to now figure out DYNAMICALLY if `report1` is filled already, if `report2` is ready, so on. I don't think I can do this from after I query the db this way, so i assume i need another query, or is there a way i can alter the query to do so?

Hopefully this makes sense!

Comment: is there any way to check if report is filled already in database ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18114458/fastest-way-to-determine-if-record-exists

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  Also, DB2 and MySQL are very different databases.  Tag only with the database you are really using.