# Difference between SELECT COUNT(*) and SELECT true finding specific row in a billion rows table

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have a table with maybe 3-5 billions rows. I need to check if a specific value is in that table, which is the fastest way?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM schema.table WHERE row = 'pattern';   -- Must return 1 or 0
```

vs

```
SELECT true AS is_in_table FROM schema.table WHERE row = 'pattern'   -- Must return true or no one row at all
```

Which is the best way to get the 'fastest' result using the appropriate column indexing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sql: How to properly check if a record exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253960/sql-how-to-properly-check-if-a-record-exists)

Comment: MySQL or PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fastest way is to put an index on `schema.table(row)`.

Then you can execute:

```
SELECT true AS is_in_table
FROM schema.table
WHERE row = 'pattern' 
LIMIT 1;
```

For this formulation, the `LIMIT` is important, unless you have explicitly declared `row` as unique (and even then I'm not 100% sure that MySQL will keep this in mind for the query).

The `COUNT(*)` will need to look for every value that might match, before returning a row.  If the column is declared unique, then the performance should be similar between the two versions.