# How to compare values from two columns of a table in c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, compare

I have a table in (local database c#) which has two columns (name1 and name2) and i have already inserted names in both columns.
now i need to check if any similar name in the two columns exist or not.
if a name exists, just show mw a  MessageBox.Show("this name exist"); 
How can i do that?
Thanks.

Comment: you can write something like this select count(last_name) frm tbl where last_name in (select first_name from tbl) .. Or you can also use intersection of two columns

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Would you like to compare the existing name1 and name2 columns or do you have a new value that you would like to compare to all the values name1 and name2? What have you tried?

Comment: I need only to compare the existing name1 and name2 columns

Answer (score 0):

There is already a subject close to your question :

[Sql: How to properly check if a record exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253960/sql-how-to-properly-check-if-a-record-exists/)

And I do think SQL count return 0 "if no rows" so you just have to make a simple condition to show your MessageBox().

Edit: if you want to check for similar name apply the same verification manipulation to both of your columns then compare both count.

(Sorry I'm french my English is approximate)

Comment: The link which you sent belongs to MSql-server.
I need two compare two columns in C#. and i don't know how to do it

Comment: Ow you dont know how to make sql request in c# ? Let me know if im right y will edit my answer.

Comment: 1) I have a column in C# local database which named "name1".i already inserted 10 names into it.
2) i have also a "textbox2". when i enter a name in this text box it saves the new name in second column which named "name2"
3) now i want to compare the recent value from "name2" column to all values in "name1" column.
4)if the recent name, existed in "name1" then showMessagebox("exists")

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure what it is that you exactly want.
This sql will list all name1 that have an equal name2:

```
SELECT name1 FROM theTable t1
WHERE name1 IN (
  SELECT name2 FROM theTable)
)
```

Of course you need to change `theTable` to the real name of your table.

If you want to run the SQL in C# you can follow the documentation. For example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader